# django modeltranslation registers "0" models

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I have a Django project that employs modeltranslation. On the development box, it registers 10 models and works flawlessly.

On the production server, when started it notifies that it has registered "0" models (instead of 10) and doesn't throw any exceptions. However when any admin page that shows a should-be-registered model is visited, the `NotRegistered` exception is thrown.

All non-admin pages, and admin pages that don't include translated models work without problems.

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the modeltranslation folder from the project folder into the packages folder resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

have a look into your database, i would bet that "syncdb" did not add the required colums/tables

if you have no production data on the database: simple delete it and re-sync it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that was not the case.

Comment: @bmaeser what if I have data in my database how can I do?